# Running Oracle DB Server on RHEL with less memory

Tags: redhat, oracle

I have a VM/Hyper-V for RHEL 7 where I need to install Oracle DB Server (12.1.0.2.0) - Standard Edition (SE2) along with App server, apache, local LDAP and other products for Developer Coding

I want to run the Oracle with as less memory as possible, so that my VM is optimum. How to start a Oracle Server Instance with minumum memory

Answer (score 0):

The question is not as simple as it seems.

First of all, how much memory does your instance use now? Maybe it worth leave it as it is?

Second, do you use Automatic Memory Management (AMM) or Automatic Shared Memory Management (ASMM)?

To check it out you shoud connect ot your instance as SYSDBA and say:

*SQL> show parameter target*

If *memory_target* is set to nonzero value, then you are using AMM. If *memory_target* is zero and *sga_target* is nonzero, then you are using ASMM. If both *sga_target* and *memory_target* are zero, then you are not using automatic management, which is unlikely.

Next, check wether you are using spfile
(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12031587/how-to-check-whether-oracle-instance-is-started-using-pfile-or-spfile) and backup it.

Then for AMM

*SQL> alter system set memory_target=1500M scope=spfile;*

or for ASMM

*SQL> alter system set sga_target=1200M scope=spfile;*

*SQL> alter system set sga_max_size=1200M scope=spfile;*

and restart your instance.

If you are yousing pfile (not spfile), then just edit it with any text editor, set the values and restart the instance.

**Beware!** Oracle requires not less than **1GB** of memory. If you set your memory_target too low, your instance won't start and you'll had to recreate your spfile.

Answer (score -1):

You can set the kernel parameters and configure the resource limits,for example /proc/sys/kernel/shmall , /proc/sys/kernel/sem , /proc/sys/kernel/shmmax , /proc/sys/fs/file-max ,/proc/sys/net/core/rmem_max etc.It will help you to start oracle with taking minimum physical memory.